# Is running a for loop faster on a quantum computer than a classical computer?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, programming

Curious to understand if I run for loop within a quantum algorithm, and lets say I want the quantum algorithm to run in classical run time of O(1). Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, quantum computers can't run for-loops faster in general.

There are certain specific tasks that can be done using a for-loop that can instead be done in a different way on a quantum computer, with fewer total operations. For example, Grover search can replace the loop `for x in range(N): if predicate(x): y = x` with something that uses $O(\sqrt{N})$ calls to `predicate` instead of the $N$ that the for loop is using.