# What is the best way to use loop statements on a quantum computer?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, classical-computing

I am interested in solving a time dependent linear partial differential equation of the form $Ax=b$ which, in classical computing, would amount to looping over solutions of $Ax=b$ where $b$ is updated each step.

My question is, is there a quantum analog to the looping procedure that I have described? If not, does that imply that to solve this one would need to write a loop on the classical system which calls the quantum solver each step? In case it is relevant, I am using the IBMQ system.

This question is related to this [post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12888/is-running-a-for-loop-faster-on-a-quantum-computer-than-a-classical-computer).

Comment: isn't this the same question asked in the linked post?

Comment: It is certainly similar, but different because the linked question asked **if** loops are faster on a quantum versus classical computers. I understand that they are not, but I am looking for a solution to the problem that I face (see post). Additionally, I posted a comment to the other post but was told to ask a new question.

Comment: so you are asking if there is a quantum algorithm to solve linear equations? (that doesn't look like a partial differential equation the way you wrote it). If so, are you aware of [HHL09](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algorithm_for_linear_systems_of_equations)? The title of the post should be updated to reflect what you are actually asking. As of now, the question in the title looks like essentially a duplicate of the linked post

Comment: No, this is not what I am asking. A partial differential equation can be discretized and written in the form $Ax=b$. I am already working with the HHL algorithm to solve simple **steady** pde's. In the future, I hope to solve **unsteady** pde's which, on a classical computer, involves looping over the system $Ax=b$ wherein each iteration $b$ is updated from the solution of $x$. I would like to find out if there is some analogue of this iterative process on a quantum computer which would not involve a loop.

Comment: that is all information which should be added to the question, to make it clear what exactly you are asking